# Java Timers - Functions called not completing!

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I have a `TimerTask task` calling a function `onTimerComplete()` in its `run()`

`onTimerComplete()` looks something like this:

```
private void onTimerComplete(){
  myFunc1();
  myFunc2();
}
```

I make a `Timer t` and I schedule the `TimerTask` with `t.schedule(task, 2000);`

The problem is, when the timer is up and the task runs my `onTimerComplete()` but that function does not finish.  It runs `myFunc1()` but never finishes it nor does it ever call `myFunc2()`

However, if I call `onTimerComplete()` directly, everything works.

What's the deal here?

Comment: I fixed the issue!
The problem was that I was trying to update UI elements from a different thread than the UI thread, which I didn't know was a no-no.

So instead of using a `Timer` I used made a class that extends `AsyncTask` and had it do the same thing as the timer.  Now using the extended `AsyncTask` everything works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myFunc1()` starts, but never finishes, then it's most likely that the problem is in that function.

You need to be aware that this function will be called in a separate thread. There is the possibility that there is some kind of unwanted interaction between two threads. ([Description here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html).)

If `myFunc1()` uses some variables that are also used in other concurrent activities, you may need to synchronize parts of your code. The [concurrency tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) might help you work out what the problem is, and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Upon further reading/testing it's definitely a threading issue.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!